# Getting values from 3 tables where two of those are self-joined

Tags: sql, postgresql

### **Problem Introduction:**

I'm working on a faker e-banking system as a side project for practicing my SQL skills (which are super bad), and I'm now stuck at a point where I want to pull data from two tables but cannot do that with joins

So, basically I have a users table which looks like this:
[image]

And I have a transactions table which saves the sender id, receiver id, amount, and date. And it looks like this: 
[image]

### What I want to achieve:

Now, I want to create a query that extracts the data in the transactions table in a way such that if I specified an ID of n (somewhere in the query), I'd get all of the transactions that user with ID of n made in a way that it **displays the first name of both sender and receiver of all of theses transactions**. 
I've been doing a lot of joins/subquery stuff to extract that information but I really can't seem to find a solution.

I'm using PostgreSQL btw.

Notes:

1. Sender & Receiver are not the same person
2. I want to display the first name of both the sender & receiver

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Hi @MinaNicola both sender and receiver are same person or different persons? Please provide your expectations as as per input table if possible.

Comment: Hello @RahulBiswas sender & receiver are different people and not the same person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by joining to the `users` table twice (you'll have to give it a separate name for each join). The following snippet leaves out some detail but illustrates the idea -

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  transactions t
  INNER JOIN users s ON t.sender = s.id
  INNER JOIN users r ON t.receiver = r.id
```

Answer (score 0):

in the transaction table I understand that the sender and receiver columns are the ids of the customers in the users table.

Filter all the transactions in which a jane user with id 17 has received a transaction (for simplicity I will use *, but ideally you should select the columns you need)

select * from users, transactions where users.id=transactions.receiver and users.id='17'.

the same but for jane shipments

select * from users, transactions where users.id=transactions.sender and users.id='17'.

if you want all the jane transactions
select * from users, transactions where users.id=transactions.receiver and users.id=transactions.sender and users.id='17'.

if you want to further filter by an amount of money sent

select * from users, transactions where users.id=transactions.sender and users.id='17' and amount > 100

finally
select first_name from users, transactions where users.id=transactions.receiver and users.id=transactions.sender and (users.id='17' or users.id='18' )

finally finally
select first_name from users, transactions where users.id=transactions.receiver and users.id=transactions.sender

Comment: you have an error in your query "all jane transactions" ... that would return only those sent by Jane to Jane ..

Comment: it is a example of natural join, only show diferent posibilities